# Dynamic of Alfvén waves in a hot magnetized plasma

Tags: plasma-physics, kinetic-theory, magnetohydrodynamics

I'm trying to derive the dispersion relation of **Alfvén waves (AW)** by solving analytically the Vlasov-Maxwell equations for a magnetized hot plasma but I'm confused. A simple question, to treat AW using kinetic theory, is it enough to consider only the dynamics of **hot electrons**, or should **ions** be included?

Comment: I'm coming from the fluid dynamics side of MHD studies, but I usually see it derived under a single species (probably the ions b/c I seem to recall $i$ subscripts) instead of both ions and electrons.

Comment: @kyle-kanos kinetically we could treat the ions alone without the electrons?

Comment: I would assume yes, but like I said, my background was on the fluid dynamics side of MHD; I never really spent much time doing kinetic theory so I could be completely wrong.

Comment: If you are trying to work out the dispersion relation for kinetic Alfven waves, you will need to worry about electrons since $k_{\perp} \rho_{ce}$ ~ 1 can be satisfied...

Comment: @honeste_vivere To my knowledge solutions of the transverse dispersion relation with propagation parallel to the magnetic field **B** include the **RH** and **LH** branches. At low frequency in **RH** we encounter the **Alfvén modes**. These modes can be found by considering a plasma of electrons alone or electrons and ions?

Comment: Umm, for parallel propagation Alfvenic modes are left-hand polarized with respect to the magnetic field.  Fast/magnetosonic/whistler modes are right-hand polarized.  It's only for oblique propagation and in the kinetic limit that the kinetic Alfven wave (note this is very different from the MHD version) can be a RH, and only for certain wave normal angles and certain plasma betas.

Comment: @honeste_vivere Excellent answer, thank you. But you did not give me an answer, for these LHCP alfvénic modes, what configuration of constituents is possible: only electrons, only ions or mixture of electrons-ions. Please do you have references on the derivation of the dispersion relation of LHCP alfvénic modes?

Comment: Just look up "ion cyclotron waves" or "electromagnetic ion cyclotron waves" (aka EMIC waves) for the LHCP modes.

Comment: @honeste_vivere Thank you.

Comment: @honeste_vivere please a title of the best reference textbook who cover all these waves.

Comment: A good (and very thorough) book is Krall, N.A. and A.W. Trivelpiece _Principles of plasma physics_, McGraw-Hill Kogakusha, 1973.  Another, much more introductory option is Gurnett, D.A. and A. Bhattacharjee _Introduction to Plasma Physics:  With Space and Laboratory Applications_, Cambridge University Press, 2005.

Comment: Thank you honeste_vivere